# How does Couchdb store duplicated attachments?

Tags: couchdb

I have a CouchDB database which stores mostly document attachments.

The files are sored in db with URL following structure:
 /db-name/numeric-file-id/official-human-readable-file-name.ext

There is always only one attachment to one document.
Today I have computed the md5 sums of all of the files and it seems that many of them are duplicates.

I am wondering if couchdb is aware of duplicate attachments and internally stores only some kind of a pointer to a file, and keeps track of reference count, or just simply stores each attachments as is.

I mean, if I put 5 identical 100MB files as attachments, will the database use 100MB or 500MB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also couldn't find a direct answer to this question in the CouchDB docs, so I devised a simple empirical test (using CouchDB 1.4):

*Experiment:*

I incrementally added 3 documents, each with several large (multi MB) attachments that were identical between documents. I then examined the size on-disk of the resulting db.couch file after each document insert.

*Results:*

The db.couch file increased from 8MB to 16MB and then 24MB for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd document inserts, respectively.  So, CouchDB does **not** appear to be deduplicating identical attachments on different documents.  Manually compacting the database after the three documents were added made no difference in the file size, so it's also unlikely that some background maintenance process would get around to noticing/fixing this.

This lack of attachment deduplication is a curious omission given the following three observations:

1. The authors were concerned enough about efficiently handling large attachments that they added automatic gzip compression of stored attachments (for those with MIME types that indicate some kind of text content.)
2. Adding an attachment causes an MD5 digest to be calculated and stored with the metadata for the attachment.
3. CouchDB does seem to deduplicate identical attachments shared among multiple revs of the **same** document that are still being held in the DB (probably one use of the MD5 digest).

Given these factors, it is surprising that CouchDB isn't more intelligent in this regard, as it would be a valuable and (likely) straightforward optimization.